# Can't login to Ubuntu 18.04 desktop (only wayland)

Tags: gnome, xorg, gnome-shell, gtk, xserver

I have an XPS 9560 with Ubuntu 18.04.03
Today I had a small problem with undocking from my desktop screen so I tried  to restart gnome (Alt+F2 r) and that seemed to take some time so I hard-shutdown the machine by long pressing the power button.
After I restarted the machine - any attempt to log in ends up with desktop showing for a brief moment and then jumping back to login screen.
When I login into wayland however, it works.

Any suggestions for how I might fix this issue?
Thanks